# sql query is not working in case of number is in decimal

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query, it is showing the empty result but the record exist in table.
Please let me know how can do it

```
select * from wp_rg_lead_detail where lead_id=5047 and field_number=1.6
select * from wp_rg_lead_detail where lead_id=5047 and field_number=1.6
```

in both case query return the empty result.but data exist in table.

data type of the field_number is float in database.

Comment: You shouldn't compare floats for equality: have a look at for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839460/why-doesnt-this-sql-query-return-any-results-comparing-floating-point-numbers

Comment: but I have mix value eg. 2,3, 1.3,1.6.8.1,8.5,8.6 I wanna values regarding this from the database, if I use >= and  <= equal then it will return the multiple results not corresponding the field_number as 1.3 or 1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the column to to decimal or numeric,they store exact numeric data values.Floats are always approximative numbers(in the way that are stored)

EDIT:Try it like this

```
select * from wp_rg_lead_detail where lead_id=5047 and format(field_number,1)=1.6
```

Comment: but in table I have both value for example 2 , 4, 1.3,1.6 I am using the gravity form so it is the id of the subfields.