# MS SQL Float Decimal Comparison Problems

Tags: t-sql, comparison, decimal

I'm in the process of normalising a database, and part of this involves converting a column from one table from a `FLOAT` to a `DECIMAL(28,18)`.  When I then try to join this converted column back to the source column, it returns no results in some cases.

It seems to bee something to do with the ways its converted.  For example, the  `FLOAT` converted to a `DECIMAL(28,18)` produces:

```
51.051643260000006000
```

The original `FLOAT` is

```
51.05164326
```

I have tried various ways of modifying the `FLOAT`, and none of these work either:

```
CAST(51.05164326 AS DECIMAL(28,18)) = 51.051643260000000000
STR(51.05164326 , 28,18) = 51.0516432599999990
```

The reason for the conversion is due to improving the accuracy of these fields.

Has anyone got a consistent strategy to convert these numbers, and be able to ensure subsequent joins work?

Thanks in advance

CM

Comment: Floating-point numbers are not exact numbers, but approximations. The conversion to strings usually rounds it so that it looks like an exact number, while the exact representation is actually different. You shouldn't try and join on floats.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have a lot of choice.  Could you recommend a way to get round this though?

Comment: I'd try and convert/cast it to the `decimal` and then round it to 14 digits using [`ROUND()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your application, you need to consider how many decimal places you need. It looks like in reality you require about 8-14 decimal places not 18.

One way to do the conversion is `cast(cast(floatColumn as decimal(28,14)) as decimal(28,18))`.

To do a join between a decimal and float column, you can do something like this:

```
ON cast(cast(floatColumn as decimal(28,14)) as decimal(28,18)) = decimalColumn
```

Provided the double-cast is the **same** double-cast used to create the `decimalColumn`, this will allow you to make use of an index on the `decimalColumn`.

Alternatively you can use a range join:

```
ON floatColumn > decimalColumn - @epsilon  AND floatColumn < decimalColumn + @epsilon
```

This should still make use of the index on `decimalColumn`.

However, it is unusual to join on decimals. Unless you actually *need* to join on them or need to do a direct equality comparision (as opposed to a range comparison), it may be better to simply do the conversion as you are, and document the fact that there is a small loss of accuracy due to the initial choice of an inappropriate data type.

For more information see:

- [Is it correct to compare two rounded floating point numbers using the == operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236439/is-it-correct-to-compare-two-rounded-floating-point-numbers-using-the-operato)
- [Dealing with accuracy problems in floating-point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: Sorry for the tardy response, it took a while to get round to testing.  This answer however does work!  Thank you!